# Fail to update relational table in access database using VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I am using access as my database in vb.net
I am using the drag and drop datasource approach to set up its dataset, data grid view , table adapter, table binding source.

I have two table , A and B
A is the parent table, B is children table
So there is a foreign key (say A.id )in B

When i tried to edit A and save it.
There will be an error come out.
It told me that B has a related record of A,
so i cannot modify or del A

I feel very confused of what it means
I did not edit column id in A (which is a foreign key in B) , i just edit others column
I don't understand why i still cannot save it

When i try to save :
the tableAdapterManager is using UpdateAll Method to update whole dataset
I tried to use the tableAdapter of A and B to update their individual dataset.
It comes out the same result no matter what the order of tableAdapter update method is

Really thanks someone who can answer my question :):)

Comment: You need to go back to the database and see what the relationships are. The error is likely to be an accurate.

Comment: Include lots of code.  Full schema of the table, UpdateCommand on the manager, whether `id` is set as the primary key or not, stack trace of any exception that you see and any code mentioned in that stack trace.